# My query doesn't work Postgresql-Python

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Im having in my database a table with name **sounds**.Table sounds got these columns :

*Start_Time,End_Time,Salience_Label,Class_Label,Bitrate,Bitdepth,Samplerate*

I'm using a combobox which values are my column names.I also have an entry where i write some values.I want to query my database (choose something from the combobox and write something in the entry).I get right values from the combobox and from the entry (I print them).
So i connecto to db with command

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
cursor = conn.cursor() //create cursor
```

After this i want to create my query string

```
 SQL = "SELECT * FROM sounds WHERE "+str(app.box.get())+" = '"+str(entry_text)+"'"
```

and then i try to query my db with the command

```
cursor.execute(SQL)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
     print row
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

i have choose from combobox the value **Bitdepth** and i have writtern in entry the value **1536**.
But from the cmd i got this message

ProgrammingError: column "bitdepth" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM sounds WHERE Bitdepth = '1536'

I know that this is not the correct way to query my db.Please help,thank you!

Comment: Your query should look like `SELECT * FROM sounds WHERE "Bitdepth" = '1536'`.

Comment: Thanks its working.Very nice !

Answer (score 2):

The immediate problem is that your column name is `Bitdepth` but when you specify `Bitdepth` as a SQL identifier it is *case folded to lower case*. You must double quote it to preserve case, writing `"Bitdepth"` instead.

However, read on.

---

You're writing insecure code that's vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Don't use string concatenation to build SQL.

Fixing this will also fix your error. If the column name was constant you'd just write:

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM sounds WHERE columnname = %s"
cursor.execute(SQL, (entry_text,))
```

... but it looks like you are trying to get a *column name* dynamically from `app.box.get()`, so this won't work.

Unfortunately you *do* have to use string concatenation for that, because psycopg2 doesn't expose an identifier quoting method. It's safe if you're careful to quote the identifier, e.g.

```
quoted_colname = '"' + str(app.box.get()).replace('"','""') + '"'
SQL = "SELECT * FROM sounds WHERE "+quoted_colname+" = %s"
cursor.execute(SQL, (str(app.box.get()), entry_text))
```

The quoting done there is simple. Wrap the identifier in double quotes, and double any double quotes within the identifier name, so that `"` becomes `""`.

That way when a malicious user uses a JavaScript debugger to modify your web form and add a new option `");DROP TABLE sounds;--` to your combo box, you won't lose your data.